# How to store persistent data when using TCP socket connection?

Tags: python-2.7, circuits-framework

I am developing a network application using circuits-framework and Python 2.7. I make my own TCP server based on TCPServer class. And I'd like to know how to store some persistent info such as user login data when using TCP socket connection?

```
class MyTCPServer(TCPServer):

@handler("read")
def on_read(self, sock, data):
    """Read Event Handler"""
    return data+" from server at :"+time.strftime("%c")
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should persist this data in an object associated with the component or detached storage like a database. Have a look at circuits/web/sessions.py for example